# Can I use Textarea as form for modelformset in Django?

Tags: python, django

So I'm have this form, which is `forms.Textarea`. And I wanted this to be in formset style, so managed to do so. However what I get in the page for the input area is the little box which seems like `forms.CharField`. Let me show you the code. 
 models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="none")
```

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'rows' : 4,
        'class' : 'answers',
        })

    class Meta:
        model=Answer
        fields=['answer',]
```

views.py

```
def answerInput(request): 
    ...
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm, extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(queryset=Answer.objects.filter(authuser = request.user, questionNumber=1))
...
```

And what I get in the page looks like this: 
[image]

I can't figure out what went wrong. Any ideas? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the widget inside the forms.CharField in order for it to work.

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'rows' : 4,
        'class' : 'answers',
        }))

    class Meta:
        model=Answer
        fields=['answer',]
```